# How can I provide margins for a number of floating thumbs so that they go from left border to right border?

Tags: css, margin

I have a div 680 pixels wide where I want to show a number of thumbnails. Each thumb is 64 pixels wide and there's a margin of 24 pixels between them. Then 8 * 64 + 7 * 24 = 680. But the eighth thumb will also apply its margin, so that it doesn't fit anymore within the 680 pixels (8 * (64 + 24) = 704).

I fixed it by manually setting the margin of every other eighth thumb to 0, but I was wondering if CSS can handle this in a proper way.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/ekorap/1/edit)'s the code.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp this may be useful

Comment: If you want not to apply margin to the last div. then you can use :last-child selector.

Comment: Would it make sense to use a left margin instead of a right one? Use a left margin for each thumb except the one that is first in its row. Something like:
==============================================================================
.thumb {float:left; margin: 8px 0px;}
.notFirst {margin-left:24px;}

Comment: @uchamp - 'fraid not. It would only work for the first line, but not the second line (9th thumb), third line (17th thumb), etc. Thanks for your thoughts, though.

Comment: @naresh - Won't work if there are several lines of thumbs. See my comment to uchamp 2 cm up.

Comment: @stevenvh, ah! I thought you could control what class goes where while rendering the thumbnails. But, that would be similar to what you're doing currently. It works but not how you want it to :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using the [nth-child](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/) selector.

```
img:nth-child(8n) { margin:0 }
```

What you're saying here is: "For every 8th img-element, apply a margin of 0".

[**Here's your updated code**](http://jsbin.com/ekorap/5/edit) - I also removed the inline CSS.

Take note this [isn't supported by all browsers](http://caniuse.com/css-sel3).

Comment: Im interested in how to do it without adding a new `<div id="thumbs">` around the thumbs?

Comment: @MarcoK - That's it exactly, thanks a bunch. I was aware of first and last, but I didn't know about nth.

Comment: Yes you can using `img:nth-child(8n+3)` . This means: "For every 8th img-element, starting from the third, apply this CSS" ([your updated code](http://jsbin.com/ekorap/8/edit)) . Take note this is **really** ugly, since adding more images to the page would break it completely. I would strongly suggest to add a container for stuff like this. Any reason not to?

Comment: @stevenvh No problem, glad to help out! Just remember that IE8 doesn't work with these kind of selectors (but with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) you can make it work with this selector). If this is what you were looking for, feel free to mark to answers as correct.

Comment: @MarcoK - I will accept it tomorrow. I always wait a day to give aothers the chance to answer as well. (In the US they're asleep right now, for instance.) Though this answer solves my problem others may shed a different light on it. (Just teasing you to improve it vene further! :-))

Comment: If I were to add a containing div around the thumbnails I would prefer adding a 24px negative left margin on the container and applying the 24px left margin on all thumbnails.                  .thumbnailcontainer{
  margin-left:-24px;
}                                                                           .thumbnail {float:left; margin: 8px 0px 8px 24px;}

Comment: @uchamp - that's an idea, and I would suggest you post it as an answer, if there wasn't the `nth-child` specifier, which is exactly what I was looking for. I just didn't know it exists.

Answer (score 1):

Using `img:nth-child(8n)` is correct answer but it will only work if we make another `<div>` surrounding thumbs and then apply `margin: 12px 0` on every 8th child that is *in this case* also an 8th img-element.

The point is: it is *not* applying for every 8th *img-element*. This selector is selecting every 8th *child* element that is also an `img`. There is a subtle but important difference.

I.e. if in a container there is one paragraph and list of images then 8th image would not be selected with img:`nth-child(8n)` selector as it is not 8th child. In that case 7th img would be 8th child and thus selected. Here is [example](http://jsbin.com/ekorap/17/edit).

Comment: In that case @stevenvh can use :nth-of-type() but, again the issue would be supporting older version of IE.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a container around the thumbnails and specify a negative left margin on it, equal to the spacing, which in your case is 24px. Then simply add a left margin on all images. The container's negative margin would act like a gutter for the margin of the first image in each row ...

```
*Example CSS*
.thumbnailcontainer{ 
    margin-left:-24px; 
    } 
.thumbnail { 
    float:left; 
    margin: 8px 0px 8px 24px; 
    } 

*Example HTML markup*
<div class="thumbnailcontainer">
    <img src="thumb1" class="thumbnail">
    <img src="thumb2" class="thumbnail">
    <img src="thumb3" class="thumbnail">
    ....
</div>
```